# "The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded " error when trying to decode Base64 in JS which has been encoded in Java

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I have a problem when trying to pass some data from Java to JS. 
The original data is of type `byte[]`.

On the Java side I'm using:

```
byte[] data = some_data;
return Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(data)
```

On the JS side I'm trying to use:

`atob(b64Data)`

While I do that I'm experiencing the error from the topic:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be
>   decoded is not correctly encoded.

Note: removing `.withoutPadding()` yields the same result.

My question is, how to rework the code so that the error no longer appears?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: What is your `b64Data` in JavaScript? What you see when you print/log it? How do you receive it?

Comment: Encoding issue?

Comment: I'm sending the data via STOMP over WebSocket using SockJS. The data is a binary for an excel file which has over 40M characters. I could try to see if the beginning of the file shows something but I believe that this data should be sent 'as is' from the Java server.

Comment: Could you try encoding simple string meanwhile? Your codes look correct, so the problem might be in the data (is too long)

Comment: I have found the solution to my problem and posted the answer. Since this does not have anything to do with base64 I will change the tags of the question to better suit the problem at hand. I will welcome any feedback on further edits so that the question and answer can be helpful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem in question was with STOMP client over WebSocket/SockJS on Spring side rather than the encoded data itself.

Although the data is sent from the method with signature
 `public String getDataForExcelFile`
the resulting answer got via the WebSocket looks like this:

`FrameImpl {command, headers, ack, binaryBody, body, (...) }` so instead of 
`atob(b64Data)` I needed to use `atob(b64Data.body)`.